# Why is Photoshop CS5 making huge gaps between lines when I make a line break with the ENTER key?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5

I'm not sure why, but suddenly when I use the type tool, write, and press ENTER to create a line break, the space between my current line and the new one is huge (it is as if 20 line breaks were made). But these are not 20 line breaks - it is just one (if I press backspace, I return to the former line).

I am using Arial Bold. Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you hit the Enter key next to the " key? Or did you hit the Enter key on your 10-key?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: Next to the " key.

Comment: Hmm. THe Enter key on your 10-key usually inserts a page break, which is why I asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure your line spacing is in **Auto** or a similar number to that of the font size?

[image]

Comment: I'd swear I never touched that... I don't even use that window :/... Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

check after paragraph spacing in paragraph setting tools

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also you might just be using "HARD returns" this is a press of the enter button alone. This will force your lines to have spaces between even if they're meant to be the same paragraph.

You may want to hold shift and press enter, this will give a "SOFT return", positioning text nicely below the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

It's something to do with Layer -> Type -> Convert to point / Convert to paragraph. I changed to 'paragraph' to try and make the text behave like a standard Indesign box, but I had this same problem.

It turns out, if you just use spaces to push text to the next line rather than line-breaks you can achieve the same thing. Works better for me now.

Answer (score -1):

[Look at this link](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/type/paragraph-panel/) and find the part about `Space After`, It is under `"The Paragraph Spacing Options"`

Perhaps it is this setting that is giving you a problem? Indesign often does this to my text

Comment: Forgot to give you the link: http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/type/paragraph-panel/

Comment: It is under " The Paragraph Spacing Options"

Comment: Hi Cre8LIVE, it looks as mohammad already mentioned the solution given in your answer?

Comment: Hi, on SE websites its preferred that Answers contain all relevant information even if you link to another site. Could you edit this to summarize what is in your link.

Answer (score -2):

open document then **page layout**- **size** then **more paper size** then **layout**-then **set page vertical alignment** to **TOP** - **OK** and out.....